# Firefox sometimes appends .zip to executable files

Tags: firefox

I tracked things down to [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=642333) and [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1133166). It happens you download an executable file, but the mime-type (application/zip or any other) doesn't match the file extension, which is supposedly a security feature.

The problem is, this behavior is *not* always the same. For most people the downloaded file extension will not be changed, while for a minority of people it will be changed.

What exactly could be triggering this "security" feature?

Test cases (lunatri.us/ext?type=[mimetype]&ext=[extension]):

```
mimetype            extension    result
---------------------------------------------------------
application/zip     ext=exe      test.exe OR test.exe.zip
image/jpeg          ext=exe      test.exe OR test.exe.jpg
application/jar     ext=exe      test.exe
application/jar     ext=jpg      test.jpg
```